# Xalan 2.7.1 firing CastClassException when comparing union of node-sets with boolean

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xalan

I'm using Xalan-J 2.7.1 (Interpretive processor) and I'm having the following problem (simplified version):

Having this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Elements>
  <A>
     <oneThing>1</oneThing>
  </A>
  <B>
     <otherThing>2</otherThing>
  </B>
</Elements>
```

I want to apply the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/Elements">
<Result>
    <xsl:variable name="A" select="A"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="B" select="B"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="($A|$B) and true()">
        <xsl:value-of select="string('worked')"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:if>
</Result>
</xsl:template>
```

And Xalan is firing: *org.apache.xpath.objects.XBooleanStatic cannot be cast to org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet*

As far as I know the union of the two node-set should be casted to boolean and then evaluated with the following condition. In this case it's trying to convert to node-set the result of *"true()"*.
Everything works ok if I wrap ($A|$B) with a boolean() function, but it should do it Xalan itself.

Does anyone know why it is firing that exception or why it isn't casting the union as it should?

Comment: Works fine for me using Saxon 6.5.5 (XSLT1) and Saxon 9.4.0.6 (XSLT2-capable).  Does the simplified example produce the same exception as the original? What line in the XSL is flagged as the source of the error?

Comment: Yap, it produces the same exception. The line flagged as the source of the error is the <xsl:id test... and the column is the start of the "true()" function.

Comment: Why `and true()`? This does not appear to be necessary. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: It should work anyways. In the real exaple there is a complex expression that ends up being a boolean. That's why it's just true(). It could be boolean($B) or anything else that ends up being a boolean.